# How can i implement a directed graph with strings?

Tags: c++, graph

[image: Graph]

This graph is a little bit confusing to understand, but i have to re-arrange these strings AU/C/G,AU/G,G,C/U,AC/U/AU/AC/G  into  (beginning always AU and end always CU). i have already made a count for the strings AU , C , G , AC, U so i basically need help implementing the string directed graph from the photo above  to create the result

results:

1) AU/ C / G / AU/ G / G/ AC / U / AU / AC / G / CU

2) AU/ C / G / G / AC / U / AU/ AC / G / AU / G / CU

3) AU / G / AU / C / G / G/ AC / U / AU / AC / G / CU

4) AU / G / G / AC / U / AU / AC / G / AU / C / G / CU

Comment: I didn't understand what you want, you want to implement that graph, what's that has to do with these resukts?

Comment: the result is generated by the graph for example : There are 3 AU , so u can only use that node 3 times etc... until all "part strings are used up " i already counted the AU , C, G, AC, U